# BigTable - HBase connector using Pyspark giving -- java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/TableDescriptor

Tags: google-cloud-platform, pyspark, hbase, google-cloud-bigtable, bigtable

> I am trying to execute the `Pyspark` job which writes the dataframe to `Bigtable` but getting the below error.
>
> I am executing it on Google Dataproc Cluster

Code to write the data to BigTable

```
       input_data.write \
       .format("org.apache.hadoop.hbase.spark") \
              .option('hbase.spark.use.hbasecontext', "false") \
              .options(catalog=catalog) \
              .save()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/d0a5ee7ae9a24f92958025c0d6de370e/bigtable_test.py", line 57, in <module>
    main(spark)
  File "/tmp/d0a5ee7ae9a24f92958025c0d6de370e/bigtable_test.py", line 31, in main
    input_data.write \
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 1107, in save
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1304, in __call__
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 111, in deco
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o255.save.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/TableDescriptor
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.spark.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:78)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:46)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:70)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:68)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$execute$1(SparkPlan.scala:180)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$executeQuery$1(SparkPlan.scala:218)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:215)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:176)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:132)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:131)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.$anonfun$runCommand$1(DataFrameWriter.scala:989)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$5(SQLExecution.scala:103)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:163)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:775)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:989)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:438)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveInternal(DataFrameWriter.scala:415)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:301)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.TableDescriptor
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
        ... 33 more
```

I have set up the below  extraClassPath properties for HBase connector and verified if these setup correctly.

`('spark.executor.extraClassPath', '/home/airflow/gcs/dags/lumiteam-data-transformation/cbt_test/hbase-spark-1.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar')`

`('spark.driver.extraClassPath', '/home/airflow/gcs/dags/lumiteam-data-transformation/cbt_test/hbase-spark-1.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar')`

Comment: check this out - http://javareferencegv.blogspot.com/2013/10/debugging-javalangnoclassdeffounderror.html

Answer (score 0):

It is missing the hbase-client dependency.

When you create the dataproc cluster, you need to specify hbase as the optional component:

```
gcloud dataproc clusters create <your-cluster-name> \
  --optional-components=HBASE,ZOOKEEPER \
  .. other options ..
```

And we you're submitting the job, you also need to include `/usr/lib/hbase` in the classpath:

```
gcloud dataproc jobs submit pyspark <your-job-name>.py \
  --properties='spark.driver.extraClassPath=/etc/hbase/conf:/usr/lib/hbase/*,spark.executor.extraClassPath=/etc/hbase/conf:/usr/lib/hbase/*' \
  .. other options ..
```